# python script for loop to print contents of files

Tags: python, for-loop

I need to make a Python script that creates a FASTA file containing all of records from all of the .fa files from /resources/pvalb/. The script should be able to take a list of files and output the contents of all of them (essentially mimicking the cat command from bash)

Here's what I have so far as an example:

```
> import sys
> 
> filenames = sys.argv[1:]
> 
> for filename in filenames:
>     for line in open(filename):
>         line = line.rstrip("\n")
>         print(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things to consider for your script:

- The files might contain binary data or an unrecognized text encoding
- The files may be quite large

  - They may even be larger than the memory available on your system
  - It's even possible that one "line" would be larger than the memory on your system

To solve these problems, it's best to open the files in binary mode with `'b'`, and then read them in chunks.

Here's an example doing so in chunks of up to 4 KiB each:

```py
import sys

for path in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(path, 'rb') as file:
        while data := file.read(4096):
            sys.stdout.buffer.write(data)
```

Some more tips:

- Most file systems, most SSD,  and newer HDD all store data in 4 KiB chunks, making reading and writing in 4 KiB chunks usually a very efficient way to go
- For very large files, especially in "slow" languages like Python, you can get faster performance by increasing these chunks to 1 MiB or even 10 MiB
- 1 MiB and 10 MiB chunks are common on big, distributed file systems like Lustre and BeeGFS, though these file systems can have a wide variety of block sizes.